# modify javascript with Burp, if js is in separate file, but gets loaded in the same HTTP response

Tags: javascript, html, burp

I am using Burp to intercept and modify server response. The response message has html `<script>` elements inside of it. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/real.js">
```

Since this is inside html response I have no power to actually look into and modify the real.js script, beacause hitting `"Forward"` allows to execute this js script. How can I inspect `real.js` script with Burp?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried selecting the Proxy Tab, then select 'Options' in the set of tabs below. If I remember correctly burp defaults enabled the proxy server option for:
File extension does not match (^gif$|^jpg$|^png$|^css$|^js$|^ico$) 
which will prevent the proxy from intercepting .js files. If you uncheck enabled for Intercept Server Responses you should see the js script.

[image: Burp's Proxy Options]